# How to get a pink cocktail colour (for my guava cocktail)?

Tags: recommendations, cocktails

I am trying to make my own cocktail and would like it to have a pink colour. I do not know which ingredients to add to make the cocktail appear pink, and would like some advice.

Here is what I currently put in my cocktail (currently in an experimental phase, so I plan to play around with the mixing ratios):

- White rum: Baccardi Carta Blanca 3cl
- Guava and passionfruit juice/syrup 1.5cl
- Simple syrup (1:1 mixture of sugar and water) 1.5cl
- Ice cubes
- Club Soda (fill up rest of the glass)

The guava juice (I don't really know the right english word, but it is some kind of non-alcoholic concentrated beverage that you normally dilute with water (and this one in particular is sugar free, and has a mixing ratio with water of 1/9) and then drink).

I want to enhance the guava and passionfruit flavour, but give it a nice pink colour. This drink was inspired by the Jarritos guava flavor soda (but it is somewhat expensive, so I use guava juice and club soda instead). I think I want the drink to be more sweet than bitter or sour (as I think this goes great with the guava flavour).

[image]

I hope to achieve a colour somewhat like the guava soda shown in the picture. However, when mixing the juice and other ingredients, the juice is almost dominant in flavour, but only adds the faintest of colour. The drink is almost perfectly clear.

Any tips on how to achieve this pink hue while preserving the guava flavour?
(Other tips about new ingredients and tips about mixing ratios is also appreciated, but my main concern is achieving the pink colour.)

**Edit:** See my answer below for the final recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some Ikea lingonberry syrup and some raspberry juice/syrup which seems to work nicely. Here is a picture of the final result:

[image]

Here is a picture with all the ingredients that I used in the background (except the Baccardi):

[image]

---

Here is the "updated" version of the recipe if anyone is interested: (I'll link to the exact products I used too if you want to re-create it the same way I did it)

| Ingredient | Link/ brand | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Guava and passion fruit juice/syrup | [Zeroh!](https://www.zeroh.se/smaker/passionfruit-guava) | 1.5 cl |
| Raspberry juice/syrup | [Lærum](https://www.lerum.no/saft/bringebersaft-utansukker) | 1.5 cl |
| Lingonberry syrup | [Ikea](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/dryck-lingon-lingonberry-syrup-20514918/) | 1.5 cl |
| White rum | [Baccardi Carta Blanca](https://www.bacardi.com/our-rums/carta-blanca-rum/) | 3 cl |
| Club soda | [Farris Naturell](https://www.farris.no/produkter) | - |
| Ice cubes | - | - |

I thought this drink would be nice *stirred* so thats how I usually prepare it. I fill up the bar glas with club soda untill I have 3 dl in total.

You can also make an alkohol free version/ virgin version and it still tastes pretty good!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Grenadine Sirup instead of the Simple Syrup. The red of the syrups should make the Cocktail Pink

Answer (score 2):

**How to get a pink cocktail colour (for my guava cocktail)?**

Occasionally l find it a simple solution to add a drop or two of red food colouring to a cocktail until I get the desired shade required.

Black food colouring is used when I make a cocktail as strong as hell and tastes like fire water.

Of course this works only if your cocktail is clear or has a slightly off clear taint.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using an already Pink Grapefruit soda, as in a Paloma - using a [Lavender Liquer](https://www.google.com/search?q=lavender%20liqueur) can also color the drink Pink, especially if the drink already contains Citrus.

Answer (score 0):

Pink Gin is a cocktail consisting of Gin and Angostura bitters, which make the drink appear pink'ish and give the cocktail it's name. Although I'm not sure how/whether this works with non-clear drinks.

[image: Pink Gin]

Answer (score 0):

To get a pink cocktail colour for your guava cocktail, you can add a few drops of grenadine or raspberry syrup to the drink. You can also add a few drops of food colouring or a splash of cranberry juice to achieve the desired hue. If you want to make it even more vibrant, you can add some fresh fruit such as strawberries or raspberries.

Comment: Maizied - please read existing answers before posting. Your answer reads like ChatGPT output, and doesn't say anything the other answers already give us.